# basic encryption in python using loop and if elif

Tags: python

I am trying to make a caesar cipher encryption program in python using loop and `if/elif`, but I my program returns unwanted results. There may be a little error in my programming logic and maybe someone wants to help me to fix it.

this input :

```
caesar
2
```

and should show an output:

```
ecguct
```

but my program show output : `caesar #thats wrong`

This my code I'm trying:

```
x = []
ch = ""   
i = 0
x = input(" enter words : ")
y = int(input("enter number : "))
for i in range(len(x)):
    i+1
    ch = x[i]
    if(ord(ch)>=ord('a') and ord(ch)<=ord('z')):
        chr(ord(ch)+y)
    elif(ord(ch)>ord('z')):
        (ord(ch)- ord('z')-ord('a')-1)
        x[i]=ch
    elif(ord(ch)>=ord('A') and ch<=ord('Z')):
        chr(ord(ch)+y)
    elif(ord(ch)>ord('Z')):
        (ord(ch)- ord('Z')+ord('A')-1)
        x[i]=ch
print(x)
```

I feel unsure about iteration that I made `i+1` , and also `x[i]=ch` it's right syntax?. Also I use `ord()` to change value string to integer. I need your opinion to fix it.

Comment: You have a bunch of statements in your program that don't do anything.  `i+1` and all the statements like `chr(ord(ch)+y)`1 don't have any effect, because you aren't assigning the result of them to anything.

Comment: If you don't know whether or not you have a syntax error, why did you post to Stack Overflow?  Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
We expect a working example of the problem, including appropriate code to trace the internal operation.

Comment: x is a string, as strings are immutable they dont support item assignment. x[i]=something should always throw an error. Try to start with en empty list and use .append() to fill it

Comment: btw you seem to have this redundant initialisation at the start: `x = []; ch = ""; i = 0;`

Comment: ok thank you all for the advice, i make it better next time

Answer (score -1):

You got several bugs in your code. First of all you have to turn your calculations to char again using the `chr()` function. Sometimes you do, sometimes you don't. Then you can't index strings - here `x[i]=ch`. Instead you have to assign your result to a new string using `+=` operator or some other `append` method. At last your `if` and `elif` does not cover the overflows it should. In case you input a string with a letter `y`, `z`, `Y` or `Z` it will overflow. The `if`-questions covering those overflows need to be nested inside the top level `if`-`elif` which processes the different upper case and lower case letters.
There is also a minor bug within the overflow calculation where you use a `-` minus instead of a `+` plus operation.
Here is the slightly fixed version of your code:

```py
x = input(" enter words : ")
y = int(input("enter number : "))
y = y % 26   # limit y to the amount of possible letters
result = ""

for ch in x:
    if(ch>='a' and ch<='z'):
        ch = chr(ord(ch)+y)
        if(ch>'z'):
            ch = chr(ord(ch)- ord('z')+ord('a')-1)
    elif(ch>='A' and ch<='Z'):
        ch = chr(ord(ch)+y)
        if(ch>'Z'):
            ch = chr(ord(ch)- ord('Z')+ord('A')-1)
    result += ch

print("input:", x)
print("output:", result)
```

You also can iterate directly over the letters of a string like '`for ch in x`' does without the need of extra indexing with `x[i]`. The `ord(...)` function is not required for comparison of characters.

Some further shrinking:

```py
x = input(" enter words : ")
y = int(input("enter number : "))

result = "".join ( [ [   # encrypting a string by adding a number to all letters
  c, chr((ord(c)-ord('Aa'[c.islower()])+y)%26+ord('Aa'[c.islower()]))
] [ c.isalpha() ] for c in x ] )

print("output:", result)
```

This code is harder to read and should cover some remarks on what it actually does. If you have some more code, shrinking might make it easier to understand because otherwise you have tons of files and modules within a project.